# How can I run Maven with debugging output from Job DSL?

Tags: maven, jenkins-job-dsl

How can I configure a Jenkins Maven job to be run with Maven debugging output enabled using Jenkins Job DSL?

There is `mavenOpts` for specifying options to the JVM and `properties` for specifying Maven properties, but there doesn't seem to be a way for passing arbitrary command line arguments, like `-X` for debugging output. What am I missing?

Comment: What would you like to debug of the Job DSL? The generated config.xml files ?

Comment: I would like to run Maven with `-X` so that I can see the debug output from  certain plugins.

Comment: You mean Jenkins Plugins? Or Maven Plugins? Where is the relationship to Jenkins Job DSL ?

Comment: I am using Jenkins Job DSL to configure the job where this Maven step is.

Comment: Apparently I can add arbitrary Maven command line parameters using the `targets` and `goals` parameters of the `maven` method of Job DSL.

Comment: Ah now i think i understand. You already know how to use `mavenOpts('-Xmx1024M')` but in your case i would use `goals('-X')` to add debugging output for Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a configuration like:

```
    steps {
      maven {
        mavenOpts("-Xmx1024M")
        goals("-X")
        goals("clean deploy")
      }
    }
```

The documentation for `goals` quite clearly states that it's possible to pass in arbitrary command line arguments to Maven using it, but I had passed over it, probably because of its name.